# Referencing a JTable from another class

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Java newbie here. I am using NetBeans 11.2. I am making a GUI awt app, I have a main class as a JFrame, and I need to reference the JTable on it or its model from another class.

Not to overload this post with lots of code, I created a tiny project from the tutorial [on the Oracle site](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/learn/settingup.html). Basically, a project named "CelciusConverterProject", a JFrame named "CelciusconverterGUI" as main class in package "learn". Then I plopped a jTable1 onto the frame and added a getter to CelciusconverterGUI for the table model named "getMdl()" :

```
package learn;

import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class CelsiusConverterGUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

[...]

          /* Create and display the form */
          java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
               public void run() {
                    new CelsiusConverterGUI().setVisible(true);
               }
          });
     }

     // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
     private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
     private javax.swing.JTable jTable1;
     // End of variables declaration                   

     public DefaultTableModel getMdl() {
          return (DefaultTableModel) this.jTable1.getModel();
     }

}
```

No errors so far, the Navigator pane shows getMdl as a public method.

Now I have created a new class called "Testing", but I cannot figure out how to call getMdl() from the instantiated running JFrame:

```
package learn;

import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class Testing {

     tmdl = (DefaultTableModel) <...>

}
```

Neither

```
 tmdl = new (DefaultTableModel) learn.CelsiusConverterGUI.
```

nor

```
 tmdl = (DefaultTableModel) learn.CelsiusConverterGUI.
```

is showing me my getter in the code completion window.

Probably a totally noobish question, but sorry I can't even google anyone who has asked the same question.

Answer (score 0):

You say you are "...making a Java awt app...", but you are using Swing classes. AWT is a Java UI library, and Swing is a different Java UI library that still uses some AWT components. But I think it's more useful and more accurate to say that you're writing a Java Swing app.

Your `getMdl()` method returns a `DefaultTableModel` -- does it need to return something that specific? Especially when you're just starting, it will be simpler if you can work with existing libraries without casting any more than you need to. The `JTable.getModel()` method returns `TableModel`, an interface (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html) that guarantees that whatever object is returned will implement all the methods in the interface. So unless you need to call a method that is in `DefaultTableModel` and is not in `TableModel`, then you can eliminate the castings to DefaultTableModel (the `(DefaultTableModel)` you have in a couple of places.

It is possible the code completion is confused by this casting -- if you were, in fact, attempting to cast `CelsiusConverterGUI` to `DefaultTableModel`, then it would not show you the `getMdl()` method because that doesn't exist in `DefaultTableModel`. I know you were probably trying to cast the return of `getMdl()` to `DefaultTableModel`, but the code completion logic may not realize that.

So my recommendation is to have `getMdl()` return `TableModel` and eliminate all casting to `DefaultTableModel`. I think your code completion will then show you `getMdl()` in your `CelsiusConverterGUI' class.

One more thing: Java convention calls for spelling out words in names of things; most Java programmers would use and expect `getModel()` instead of `getMdl()`.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your response. I've changed the instances of GetDefaultModel (that I had clearly aped from code I had found on the web) to TableModel, but it hasn't changed the behaviour. The Navigator does show a public class for getMdl(), but I cannot reference it from the outside. The closest I can come to is with an "tmdl = learn.CelsiusConverterGUI.getMdl();" is to get a "non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context".

Comment: The idea is, as I've been doing in C++ and Delphi some time ago, is not to have any "payload" inside the main frame. So my JFrame has this JTable1, which has its contents in its TableModel. I need to present a pointer to this TableModel to an outside class where I'll be doing the actual writing to it, sorting, deleting, etc. I can't find a way to do it in Java.

Comment: You must make a reference to the instance of your TableModel available to whomever is going to call it -- either have a method in the JFrame class to obtain it, or pass it as a parameter to a call, whatever. You seem to be trying to call the method by referring to the class, not an instance, and since it is an instance method, there's no way to do that.

Comment: I understand that, hence my original question in the OP: "I cannot figure out how to call getMdl() from the instantiated running JFrame". JFrame is extended by CelciusConverterGUI, to which I have added a public getter getMdl(). But once the application has launched the JFrame, I have no idea what it's called, and how to reference it / call it in another class.

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding another answer because we now have a better definition of the question.

You want to get a reference to the CelsuisConverterGUI object that you instantiated; to do that, you need to assign the result of the instantiation of the class to a variable and then obtain that reference somehow. Below is an example that I have not even compiled, but should be close -- it has a static variable that keeps the (only) reference to the main class, and instantiates the class the first time the getter for the instance is used:

```
public class CelsiusConverterGUI extends JFrame
{
  private static CelsiusConverterGUI mainFrame = null;
  public static getMainFrame() 
  { 
    if (mainFrame == null)
    {
      java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() { mainFrame = new CelsiusConverter(); }
    }
    return mainFrame; 
  }

  public static void main(String ... arguments)
  {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
    {
      mainFrame = getMainFrame();
      mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
  }

  // ...
}

public class Testing
{
  CelsiusConverterGUI mainFrame = CelsiusConverterGUI.getMainFrame();
  // ...
}
```